# Relation does not exist Rails/PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When trying to run all migrations to a rails app with `rake db:migrate`, keep on receiving this error:

```
`ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist at character 323
 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
 LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
```

Been through every other stackoverflow answer for this and they all seem to suggest running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` again which gives the same error.

Have also ran `rake db:create && rake db:schema:load` with no success. Even when I run `rake db:reset` the reset doesn't happen and this error loads up again.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably had 
`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` set in your `config/application.rb`

In that case, you should not have `db/schema.rb` file but should have `db/structure.sql` instead.

If that was the case, you should have run `bundle exec rake db:structure:load` (note `structure` instead of `schema`)

Answer (score -2):

[`Resetting the Database`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#resetting-the-database) The `rails db:reset` task will drop the database and set it up again. This is functionally equivalent to  `rails db:drop db:setup`.

For Heroku you need to run `heroku run rails db:drop db:setup` or `heroku run rake db:drop db:setup` if `rails db:reset` not work